# Passing declaration of struct between .cpp files without using global header file

Tags: c++, struct

Suppose I have `main.cpp` and `functions.cpp`, a `struct` type named `myStruct` was declared in `main.cpp`.

Now, I need to process an array of `myStruct` in `main.cpp` using a function in `functions.cpp`.

Sample Code:

```
// main.cpp
#include "functions.cpp"

struct myStruct {
    int x;
}
myStruct structArray[5];

int main()
{
    ...(some code)...
    process(structArray);
}
```

```
// functions.cpp
void process(struct myStruct array[])
{
   ...(some code)...
}
```

After doing some searching, I found the most common solution is to use a global header file, in which declare `myStruct`, and then include the header file in both `main.cpp` and `functions.cpp`.

Unfortunately, I am required to use ***only two files*** to complete such a program, which means I couldn't add a separate `header.h`, making me confused.

Can anyone give me some suggestions on an alternative of a global header in this situation? Thanks.

Comment: you should not include .cpp files like that, it'll cause ODR violation at some point

Comment: As an aside, you shouldn't include your headers as ```.cpp```. They should be ```.hpp (or .h)```. The code will still compile, as an ```#include``` directive is just a glorified copy-and-paste operation. So my advice would be to move the struct definition over to ```functions.hpp``` and ```#include "functions.hpp"``` inside your ```main.cpp```.

Comment: I think the main "problem" here is that your professor/lecturer/teacher seems to have  told you (or somehow implied) that function definitions *have* to be in ```.cpp ```and declarations *have* to be in ```.hpp```. That is *not true*.

Comment: Just duplicate the data - copy `struct myStruct` definition to the other cpp file. You could pass the definition with using compiler options, like `-DMYSTRUCT_DEFINE="struct myStruct { int s; };` and then use the macro in both files.

Comment: This sounds misguided. I'm guessing that it's homework, but I can't think of a reason to require only two files. Unless it's to teach how frustrating it can be to have to maintain two copies of the same `struct`, and the feeling of relief you'll have when you're allowed to do it right, with the definition in a separate header file.

Comment: @ypnos That's a good idea, thanks

Comment: @Sopel That's true, even though I somehow "solve" this problem, the code still gets a warning in some modern IDEs

Comment: @PeteBecker Good guess! It was indeed some kind of homework, and it's so confusing to require only using two .cpp files.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do that using only two .cpp files

My idea is to have declaration of `struct myStruct` in both main.cpp and fucntion.cpp and to have `process` function declaration in main.cpp. like this..

```
// main.cpp
struct myStruct {
    int x;
};
void process(struct myStruct array[]);
myStruct structArray[5];

int main()
{
    ...(some code)...
    process(structArray);
}
```

and

```
// functions.cpp
    struct myStruct {
        int x;
    };
    void process(struct myStruct array[])
    {
       ...(some code)...
    }
```

And compile each separately and link together at linking time.

Comment: * `void process(struct myStruct array[]);` has to be after `struct MyStruct` definition.

Comment: @KamilCuk 
you're right. 
I fixed it.

but it works in my IDE (visual studio 2015)

Comment: Note that the two definitions of `myStruct` need to be identical (in the sense that the compiler "sees" the exactly same set of tokens when reading each one) otherwise the program will have undefined behaviour.   This is one variant of what is known as the "one-definition rule".

Comment: @KamilCuk Thanks. While it seems that some IDE (Xcode, for example) still thinks the code is invalid and refuse to execute it, it can work when compiling directly with g++.

Answer (score 0):

`#include` is like copying and pasting contents of the file. So if you define a struct in `functions.cpp` and include this file in `main.cpp`, you can access internals of this struct there.

Note however, that by convention you SHOULD NOT include `.cpp` (or other sources) files. In this case I would rather rename `functions.cpp` to `functions.h` and declare function there, if you really need to do it using only two files.

If you really really really can not move defintion of the struct from `main.cpp` to `functions.*` for whatever reason you could also include `functions.*` in `main.cpp` after the defintion of the struct, but this is a very ugly solution. If you work with strange requirements it would be a solution tough I would do everything else to avoid that.